# Posting a JSON repeated object to server once without the need to copy?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this object it is a model but what i want to send it to node server about 30 times in one request I mean I don't want to write it 30 times can how to loop over it to create 30 copy's and then sent it ? or can I sent it just once and use node / mongoose to push it to database 30 times ??

```js
// this must be sent 30 times !! 

   const dataToSend = JSON.stringify({
        id: `${id}`,
        a: "",
        b: "",
        c: "",
        d: "",
        f: ""
    })


// later fetch function that will have a body containing all the 30 !
```

Comment: you could wrap it in a for statement then loop it 30 times. comment if you want help with it.

Comment: ok sounds good.